# Logstash can't create separate indexes

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, filebeat

I have two filebeat inputs which have tags and fields.
In my pipeline.conf I used filter logs by theirs tags.
but when the time of index create logstash takes index name as a %{[fields][log_type]}-2020-10-07.
How can I solve this? Can I able to create two separate index? 

here are my files.

**filebeat.yml**

```
- type: log 
  enabled: true
  paths:
    - D:\Git\gbase.API\Logs\*.log
  tags: ["gbaseapi"]    
  fields: {log_type: gbase}

- type: log 
  enabled: true
  paths:
    - D:\Git\finance.api\FinanceAPI\logs\*.log
  tags: ["financeapi"]
  fields: {log_type: finance}

multiline.pattern: '^[[:space:]]'
multiline.negate: false
multiline.match: after
```

**mypipeline.conf**

```
input {
 beats {
    type=>"mytest"
    port => 5044
  }
} 
filter{
    if "gbase" in [tags]
    {
       if [level] in [ "Error", "Fatal" ] 
        {
            grok { match=> ["message","%{DATESTAMP:timestamp} \[%{WORD:processId}\] %{LOGLEVEL:level} %{USERNAME:logger} %{USER:user} %{IPV4:clientIp} %{URI:requestUrl} %{USER:method}  %{GREEDYDATA:message}"] }
        }
        else
        {
            grok { match=> ["message","%{DATESTAMP:timestamp} \[%{WORD:processId}\] %{LOGLEVEL:level} %{USERNAME:logger} %{USER:user} %{IPV4:clientIp} %{GREEDYDATA:message}" ] }
        }
         mutate { gsub => ["message", "\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}.\d{4} ",""]} 
         mutate { gsub =`enter code here`> ["message", "%{level}",""]}
         mutate { gsub => ["message", "%{logger}",""]}
         mutate { gsub => ["message", "%{clientIp}",""]}
    }
    if "finance" in [tags]
    {
       if [level] in [ "Error", "Fatal" ] 
        {
            grok { match=> ["message","%{DATESTAMP:time} \[%{WORD:processId}\] %{LOGLEVEL:level} %{USERNAME:logger} %{USER:user} %{IPV4:clientIp} %{URI:requestUrl} %{USER:method} %{GREEDYDATA:message}"]}
        }
        else
        {
            grok { match=> ["message","%{DATESTAMP:time} \[%{WORD:processId}\] %{LOGLEVEL:level} %{USERNAME:logger} %{USER:user} %{IPV4:clientIp} %{GREEDYDATA:message}" ]}
        }
        mutate { gsub => ["message", "\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}.\d{4} ",""]}
        mutate { gsub => ["message", "%{level}",""]}
        mutate { gsub => ["message", "%{logger}",""]}
        mutate { gsub => ["message", "%{clientIp}",""]}
    }
   date {
        match => [ "time" , "dd/MMM/yyyy:HH:mm:ss Z" ]
        target=> "@time"
    }
}
output {
        elasticsearch 
        {
            hosts => ["http://localhost:9200"]
            index => "%{[fields][log_type]}-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
            user => "something"
            password => "something"     
        }
  stdout { codec => rubydebug }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should specify `fields` like this, instead:

```
- type: log 
  enabled: true
  paths:
    - D:\Git\gbase.API\Logs\*.log
  tags: ["gbaseapi"]    
  fields:
    log_type: gbase                      <--- change this
```